# Css spacing issue with iFrame

Tags: html, css

In a row I have an iframe google map and the next row an address but the iframe injects a block of white space and pushes the address off limit of the page, see picture;

[image: example]

Codepen-example
    https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/PJOYaa

HTML;

```
<section id="map-section">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <div class="google-map">
                            <iframe src=""
                            height="200" width="100%"
                            frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-warning col-3">
                        <div class="home-address">
                            <p class="address">
                                Address 1
                                Address 2<br>
                                33-655<br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

CSS;

```
#map-section {
    .google-map{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .address{
        font: 2em "Caveat";
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        padding-top: 2.5em;
        padding-left: 0em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the page or to working example of the problem?

Comment: Nothing unusual in the code you posted.  We would need to see a working example.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, where does that code go? In the stylesheet I assume?

Comment: I just added it with, .body{background: $bg-color; color: $font-color; margin:0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;} but didn't resolve the issue

Comment: I added this https://res.cloudinary.com/paul-seal/image/upload/v1507070620/Capture_qgzxcp.jpg[link] and still no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding 'overflow-x: hidden;' so;

```
html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Include the basic CSS browser reset if you haven't done it already: * {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box} html, body {width:100%}